# QDA vs LDA for face recognition on AT&T dataset

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I am obtaining two very different accuracies for the AT&T face database when fitting the model with lda & qda. Before using QDA I first search for the ideal regularisation parameter, AFAIK the only import parameter to fine-tune for QDA.

```
X_load,y_load = datasets.fetch_olivetti_faces(data_home="R:/DATASET/AT&T", return_X_y=True)
```

I split this into a balanced train and test sequence (8 images for training, 2 for testing per person)

```
lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(solver='svd')
lda.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred_lda = lda.predict(X_test)
y_true_lda = y_test
f1_scores_lda.append(met.f1_score(y_true_lda, y_pred_lda, average='micro'))

qda = QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis()
clf = GridSearchCV(qda, params, cv=4)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
reg_params_qda.append(clf.best_params_['reg_param'])
```

Im running this experiment for an increasing number of persons so Im keeping a python list with these parameters

```
qda2 = QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis(reg_param=clf.best_params_['reg_param'])
qda2.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred_qda = qda2.predict(X_test)
f1_scores_qda.append(met.f1_score(y_true_qda, y_pred_qda, average='micro'))
```

When i run this using the whole dataset (40 persons);

f1_scores_lda outputs 0.975

f1_scores_qda outputs 0.125

**Why is QDA performing so poorly?**

Comment: Multiple question, way too broad, shows little effort and should be closed unless you reask something specific; you're not allowed ask for recommendations on which classifier you should use; implement it then tell us what you found. Also when you say *"wants me to account for the distribution of the data of the different classes in feature-space"*, it help if you give us a distribution plot or some summary statistics. Also you might get a better answer posting or reading at [CrossValidated](https:/www.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: There are [28 questions about LDA+QDA on CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=LDA%20QDA%20is%3aquestion), recommend you skim them, at least start with the ones with the most votes. Show us some basic summary statistics or distribution plot of the different classes in feature-space, think about some fast-and-dirty transforms to make those a bit more normal, rerun the classifiers, tell us what improvement you got, look at the confusion matrix. Basically, develop an intuition for why QDA or LDA perform the way they do, per-class. Before you go classifier-shopping.

Comment: Essentially, start by answering your own Q1 and 2. Don't go further until you have a basic answer for those.

Comment: I will clean this up tomorrow, thanks for the pointers, and sorry for not being specific enough. I will edit the question and do what you suggested, thanks for taking the time to reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has been reformulated and I ended up answering it myself at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/461052/lda-vs-qda-on-the-att-dataset-poor-qda-performance)